# Scaling containers in Docker-compose and assign each one with a different network

Tags: docker, networking, docker-compose, docker-container, docker-network

I want to implement a scalable star-like network topology with docker containers.

A sketch of the topology I'm aiming to is on the bottom URL.

I have one container that would be at the center of this network (C1) and have also another two containers (C2 and C3) that are connected to each other. C3 must ve isolated fron any other container except C2. C2 and C1 are connected to each other.

On my Docker-compose file, I defined a network to connect C2 with C3, and a different one to connect C1 with C2.

If I just launch one of each container, everything runs smoothly. The problem starts when I try to scale the group C2-C3 n times, that I don't know how to do that with compose:
1. Is it possible to scale networks? 
2. Is it possible to scale groups of containers like I want to?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/pYx4q.jpg

Comment: Seems more appropriate for research over on https://serverfault.com/

Comment: @jdv thanks! I'll post this question there.